# not able to remove decimal places

Tags: android, flutter, dart, weather-api

```
double? dTemprature = weather.temperature?.celsius;

sTemprature = dTemprature.toString();

List<String> list = sTemprature.split('.');

sTemprature = list[0] + "." + list[1].substring(0,1);

print ("Weather Temperature: "+sTemprature.toString());
```

its coming 26.4000000000000
I wanted 2.4

Comment: Can you show what data are you receiving in `weather.temperature?.celsius`?

Comment: Use `sTemprature.toStringAsFixed(1)` instead of `sTemprature.toString()`

Comment: tried    its coming like this 
The method 'toStringAsFixed' isn't defined for the type 'String'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toStringAsFixed'

Comment: double? get celsius => _kelvin != null ? _kelvin! - 273.15 : null;

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below method,
`double number = double.parse(sTemprature.toStringAsFixed(1));`

Comment: tried same error